# Me sale el error Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Tags: php, javascript, mvc

> Estoy recibiendo un error cuando quiero actualizar un elemento de mi base de datos. Estoy haciendo un CRUD de Ingredientes, y la parte de crearlos fue bien, el problema lo tengo a la hora de editar.

**ingredientes.php**

> Tengo 3 inputs en un form, tanto `editarPrecio` como `editarUnidad` llegan correctamente, el problema lo tengo con `editarIngrediente`, que sería el nombre del mismo. (pongo unicamene los 4 elementos, omito etiquetas `div` y `form` pero todo eso funciona bien)

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="editarIngrediente" id="editarIngrediente" required>  
<input class="form-control" type="text" id="editarPrecio" min="0" step="any" name="editarPrecio" required>
<select class="form-control" name="editarUnidad">

    <?php

         $item = null;
         $valor = null;

         $unidades = ControladorUnidades::ctrMostrarUnidades($item, $valor);

         echo '<option value="" id="editarUnidad">Aca ira la unidad</option>';
         foreach ($unidades as $key => $value){

           echo '<option value='.$value["id"].'>'.$value["nombre"].' ('.$value["nomenclatura"].')</option>';
           }
?>              
</select>

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Guardar</button>
```

**ingrediente.js**

> Con JS le cargo el modal con los datos del elemento seleccionado, esta parte funciona bien

```
/*=====================
EDITAR INGREDIENTE
=======================*/
$(".tablaIngredientes tbody").on('click', 'button.btnEditarIngrediente', function(){


var idIngrediente = $(this).attr("idIngrediente");

var datos = new FormData();

datos.append("idIngrediente", idIngrediente);

$.ajax({

    url: "ajax/ingredientes.ajax.php",
    method: "POST",
    data: datos,
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(respuesta){

        var datosIngrediente = new FormData();
        datosIngrediente.append("idUnidad", respuesta["id_unidad"]);

        $.ajax({

            url: "ajax/unidades.ajax.php",
            method: "POST",
            data: datosIngrediente,
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(respuesta){


                $("#editarUnidad").val(respuesta["id"]);
                $("#editarUnidad").html(respuesta["nombre"]+' ('+respuesta["nomenclatura"]+')');


            }


        })

        $("#editarIngrediente").val(respuesta["nombre"]);
        $("#editarPrecio").val(respuesta["precio"]);

    }


})


})
```

**ingredientes.controlador.php**

> Acá es donde visualizo el problema, aunque no se si efectivamente está en este código.
>
> **CUAL ES EL PROBLEMA:**
>     LA LINEA

```
echo '<script>console.log('.$datos["nombre"].')</script>';
```

> Esta linea la puse para ver como se estaban mandando los datos. Si yo reemplazo `$datos["nombre"]` por `$datos["id_unidad"]` o `$datos["precio"]` me imprime valores correctos en consola. En cambio usando `$datos["nombre"]` me retorna el error **Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list**

```
/*==============================================
EDITAR INGREDIENTE
==============================================*/

static public function  ctrEditarIngrediente(){

    if(isset($_POST["editarIngrediente"])){

        if( preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9ñÑáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚüÜ ]+$/', $_POST["editarIngrediente"]) && preg_match('/^[0-9.]+$/', $_POST["editarPrecio"])){

            $tabla = "ingredientes";

            $datos = array(
                "nombre" => $_POST["editarIngrediente"],
                "id_unidad" => $_POST["editarUnidad"],
                "precio" => $_POST["editarPrecio"]
            );

            echo '<script>console.log('.$_POST["editarIngrediente"].')</script>';
            $respuesta = ModeloIngredientes::mdlEditarIngrediente($tabla,$datos);


            if($respuesta == "ok"){

                echo '<script>
                swal.fire({
                    type: "success",
                    title: "El ingrediente ha sido editado correctamente",
                    showConfirmButton: true,
                    confirmButtonText: "Cerrar",
                    closeOnConfirm: false

                }).then(function(result){
                    if(result.value){
                        window.location = "ingredientes";

                    }   

                });
                </script>';

            }


        } 




                else {
                    echo '<script>
            swal.fire({
                type: "error",
                title: "Los datos no pueden estar vacíos o contener carateres especiales",
                showConfirmButton: true,
                confirmButtonText: "Cerrar",
                closeOnConfirm: false

            }).then(function(result){
                if(result.value){
                    window.location = "ingredientes";

                }   

            });
            </script>';




                }





    }
}
```

**ingredientes.modelo.php**

> Este es el código encargado de actualizar la base de datos. (tal vez haya algun problema acá? )

```
/*============================================
EDITAR INGREDIENTE
============================================*/

static public function mdlEditarIngrediente($tabla, $datos){


    $stmt = Conexion::conectar()->prepare("UPDATE $tabla SET id_unidad = :id_unidad, nombre = :nombre, precio = :precio WHERE id = :id");   

    $stmt->bindParam(":nombre", $datos["nombre"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(":id_unidad", $datos["id_unidad"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(":precio", $datos["precio"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(":id", $datos["id"], PDO::PARAM_STR);


    if($stmt->execute()){

        return "ok";

    }else{
        return "error";
    }

    $stmt -> close();

    $stmt = null;



}
```

> Y por ultimo el archivo AJAX

**ingredientes.ajax.php**

```
class AjaxIngredientes{




/*=====================
EDITAR INGREDIENTES
=======================*/


public $idIngrediente;

public function ajaxEditaringrediente(){

    $item = "id";
    $valor = $this->idIngrediente;

    $respuesta = ControladorIngredientes::ctrMostrarIngredientes($item, $valor);

    echo json_encode($respuesta);

}




}



/*=====================
EDITAR INGREDIENTES
=======================*/

if(isset($_POST["idIngrediente"])){

    $editarIngrediente = new AjaxIngredientes();
    $editarIngrediente -> idIngrediente = $_POST["idIngrediente"];
    $editarIngrediente -> ajaxEditaringrediente();

}
```

> BUENO, ESO ES TODO. EL PROBLEMA EN CUESTION ES QUE UNA VEZ QUE ACTUALIZO UN ELEMENTO, ME SALE LA ALERTA DE SWEET ALERT INFORMANDO QUE EL CAMBIO SE EFECTUÓ, PERO NO LO VEO REFLEJADO EN LA DB. ES POR ESO QUE IMPRIMO EL `echo` EN EL ARCHIVO `ingredientes.controlador.php` Y VEO QUE NO ESTA CAPTURANDO CORRECTAMENTE LA VARIABLE `editarIngrediente`. NO SE SI EL PROBLEMA LO VENGO ARRASTRANDO DESDE `ingredientes.php`, SI ESTÁ EN EL CONTROLADOR O EN EL MODELO.
>
> Llevo ya mas de 24hs con esto y no puedo resolverlo, agradecería si alguien pudiera darme una mano

Comment: ¿En `$datos["nombre"]` tienes algún nombre de ingrediente que tenga algún caracter especial? Específicamente si alguno tiene comillas simples. Imagínate que te llega un ingrediente que se llama "Kobe's beef". Tu console.log se quedaría así: `console.log('Kobe's beef');` Ahí las comillas están mal cerradas y te daría un error de `Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list`

Comment: No, unicamente acentos y espacios en blanco. De todas maneras el error me sale para elementos que inclusive no tienen ni uno ni el otro

Comment: Ya encontré el error. Por un lado me faltaba pasar un elemento ``html`` mas, y es el ``input hidden`` que lleva el ``id`` del elemento a modificar. Y también me faltaba una linea de codigo en el  ``ingrediente.js``, al cerrar el primer llamado ``ajax`` que se encargue de cargar el ``input`` : ``$("#idIngrediente").val(respuesta["id"]);`` - No se si debería borrar la pregunta

Comment: Mani, en primer lugar enhorabuena por haber encontrado la solución. No borres la pregunta, lo que tienes que hacer es escribir una respuesta propia indicando cómo lo has resuelto, y aceptarla para que la gente que busque preguntas sin responder no le salga esta que ya está respondida.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya encontré el error. Por un lado me faltaba pasar un elemento html en **ingredientes.php**, es el input oculto que va a enviar el `id` del ingrediente:

```
<input type="hidden" name="idIngrediente" id="idIngrediente">
```

Y también me faltaba una linea de codigo en **ingrediente.js**, al cerrar el primer llamado ajax que se encargue de cargar el input :

```
$("#idIngrediente").val(respuesta["id"]);
```

> En la publicacion original me falto tambien cargar la variable `$_POST["idIngrediente"]` a la variable `datos`, pero eso en mi código ya estaba, solo que lo copié mal en esta pregunta:

```
$datos = array(
            "nombre" => $_POST["editarIngrediente"],
            "id_unidad" => $_POST["editarUnidad"],
            "precio" => $_POST["editarPrecio"],
            "id" => $_POST["idIngrediente"]
        );
```

> Gracias a todos por tomarse el trabajo de leerla.

Comment: Gracias por tomarte las molestias de escribir una respuesta con la solución :)